# Wordpress - Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client who's old site had .php extensions on every url.

I built their new site using Wordpress. The urls are all the same without the .php extension. I used an .htaccess rewrite to remove the .php extension and it works great, but the problem is I can no longer access the admin area of wordpress... here's what I've added:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+).php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Any thoughts?

Comment: ¿Are those the directives to remove the `php` extension? ¿Where is the WP rule set? ¿How is the .htaccess file? Too much information is missing, try to update your question. You have more possibilities of getting the **right** answer if you supply all the information.